# Matplotlib: Colormap changes dramatically with input size

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I'm using the prism colormap to generate a few plots. My original colormap was generated as below, and the plot looked like this (the 10 is automatically generated, but hardcoded in here for demonstration purposes). This is 10 colors for 10 inputs:

```
colors = plt.cm.prism(np.linspace(0., 1., 10))
```

[image]

When I added an extra data point (an additional point on the colormap), I noticed a complete shift in the colors represented. Any ideas how I can scale back to the rotating color cycle of the first graph? This is 11 colors for 11 inputs:

```
    colors = plt.cm.prism(np.linspace(0., 1., 11))
```

[image]

I've tried extending the number of colors represented. I can't explain the results. Using 12 colors for 11 inputs:

```
    colors = plt.cm.prism(np.linspace(0., 1., 12))
```

[image]

Using 13 colors for 11 inputs:

```
colors = plt.cm.prism(np.linspace(0., 1., 13))
```

[image]

I thought it might be an even vs odd thing, so I tried 14 colors for 11 inputs:

```
    colors = plt.cm.prism(np.linspace(0., 1., 14))
```

[image]

I can't quite figure out what the trick is to get a rotating color cycle vs. a subsection of the rainbow based on the number of inputs.

Comment: The ones that look gradiated look right - the call to the colormap between 0 and 1 should give you the full range of the colormap.  It's the other ones that don't make sense - i.e. the one on the top when you say "10 colors for 10 inputs", you are certainly not getting 10 colors, you're getting 6.  I would tend to be more suspicious of your plotting code (without being able to see it) rather than the colormap.

Comment: @Ajean would the plotting code still matter if all graphs use the exact same code, just different color maps? And the only difference between Graph #1 and Graph #2 is an extra column in the data set, otherwise it is identical.

And I think you mean 11 colors for 11 inputs -- it looks like it only gave me a single slice of the rainbow, not the full colormap.

Comment: Right, I mis-typed, sorry. Hmm. Have you tried this with other colormaps and get the same thing?

Comment: Great thought @Ajean -- just tried Flag, it's the most similar one because of its repeating cycle of colors. The rest seem to use a single start-to-finish gradient -- I didn't experience the same phenomenon, but I'm not sure the comparison would make sense because they're missing that cyclicality. I did not have this issue with Flag: [colormap reference](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)

Comment: `"(the 10 is automatically generated, but hardcoded in here for demonstration purposes)."`  -- Is it possible that the way you're calculating the number of colors has a bug somewhere? Maybe try printing out the variable to double-check. What happens if you bypass that part of your code and just put in a number?

Comment: @JoeKington - the graphs look the same when the numbers are hard coded in or calculated manually.